# Find Duplicate in Mutable Array with Only 1 Repeating element

Tags: c++, data-structures

nums is an array of size N+1 and the elements range from 1 to N with only one repeating element.
Why do we use `-1` in `nums[ abs( nums[i] ) - 1 ]` in the following Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (nums[abs(nums[i]) - 1 ] >= 0)
                nums[abs(nums[i]) - 1 ] = -nums[abs(nums[i]) - 1];
            else
                return abs(nums[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

The logic of this code is to traverse through each Element and make it negative and if encounter an already negative element then that is the duplicate but I don't understand why we use `-1` here while I'm doing dry run on paper I'm getting wrong answer

Comment: Please tell us more about what to expect in `nums` and about the question at the competetive code challanges site you are looking at.

Comment: The answer is in the part of the question that you didn't tell us -- the range of values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As you are solving a problem, you did not provide us with enough information. As to explain the specific part of you question, It is assumed that `nums` contain data like this `nums[i] < 0 && abs(nums[i]) <= nums.size()`

What I get from this line `nums[ abs( nums[i] ) - 1 ]`, it implies that `abs(num[i])` must be less than equal to `nums.size()`.So if that `abs(nums[i]) == nums.size()`, You will be accessing the array out of range. So `nums[ abs( nums[i] ) - 1 ]` keep the number within the range of `nums.size() - 1`.

Comment: What if `nums[i]` is `0`? I don't think we know enough about `nums`.

Comment: yeah, That's true. It is assumed that If the number is  num[i] < 0 && abs(nums[i]) <= nums.size().

Comment: nums is an array of size N+1 and the elements range from 1 to N with only one repeating element. i have edited the question Thankyou for Your response